# Producing histogram Map for IntStream raises compile-time-error

Tags: java-8, grouping, histogram, java-stream, aggregation

I'm interested in building a Huffman Coding prototype. To that end, I want to begin by producing a histogram of the characters that make up an input Java `String`. I've seen many solutions on SO and elsewhere (e.g:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122394/word-frequency-count-java-8) that depend on using the `collect()` methods for `Stream`s as well as static imports of `Function.identity()` and `Collectors.counting()` in a very specific and intuitive way.

However, when using a piece of code eerily similar to the one I linked to above:

```
private List<HuffmanTrieNode> getCharsAndFreqs(String s){
        Map<Character, Long> freqs = s.chars().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
        return null;
}
```

I receive a compile-time-error from Intellij which essentially tells me that there is no arguments to `collect` that conforms to a `Supplier` type, as required by its signature:

[image: Intellij's error message]

Unfortunately, I'm new to the Java 8 `Stream` hierarchy and I'm not entirely sure what the best course of action for me should be. In fact, going the `Map` way might be too much boilerplate for what I'm trying to do; please advise if so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `s.chars()` returns an `IntStream` - a particular specialization of `Stream` and it does not have a `collect` that takes a single argument; it's `collect` takes 3 arguments. Obviously you can use `boxed` and that would transform that `IntStream` to `Stream<Integer>`.

```
Map<Integer, Long> map = yourString.codePoints()
          .boxed()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                      Function.identity(), 
                      Collectors.counting()));
```

But now the problem is that you have counted `code-points` and not chars. If you absolutely know that your String is made from characters in the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), you can safely cast to `char` as shown in the other answer. If you are not - things get trickier.

In that case you need to get the single unicode code point as a character - but it *might* not fit into a `Java char` - that has 2 bytes; and a unicode character can be up to 4 bytes.

In that case your map should be `Map<String, Long>` and not `Map<Character, Long>`.

In java-9 with the introduction of supported `\X` (and `Scanner#findAll`) this is fairly easy to do:

```
 String sample = "A" + "\uD835\uDD0A" + "B" + "C";
         Map<String, Long> map = scan.findAll("\\X")
               .map(MatchResult::group)
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));


 System.out.println(map); // {A=1, B=1, C=1, =1}
```

In java-8 this would be a bit more verbose:

```
    String sample = "AA" + "\uD835\uDD0A" + "B" + "C";
    Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\P{M}\\p{M}*+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(sample);

    while (m.find()) {
        map.merge(m.group(), 1L, Long::sum);
    }
    System.out.println(map); // {A=2, B=1, C=1, =1}
```

Comment: If the fact that the stream created via `codePoints()` will count code points instead of `char`s is a problem, well, just use `chars()` like the OP does. You are trying to workaround a problem that you have created yourself.

Comment: @Holger hmm.. you might be right. so, if I wanted to see the "human readable character" and how many times it is repeated I could have simply used: `s.codePoints().mapToObj(x -> new String(Character.toChars(x)))`

Comment: A “human readable character” is another thing. There are `char`s, these 16 bit units which may map 1:1 or 2:1 to *code points*, but a (human readable) *character* might even consist of multiple code points like `U+0041 U+0308`, both being *within* the BMP, so it’s important not to mix up “`char` vs code point” issues with “code point vs character (or grapheme cluster)” issues. Your last two examples split into *characters*, but if you want to open that can of worms, you have to note that they don’t understand which characters are identical, e.g. `U+0041 U+0308` is the same as `U+00C4`…

Comment: But note that the OP seems to intent to implement a compression algorithm that doesn’t need to care about the semantics, so a histogram of `char` values would be sufficient. And don’t be surprised that there’s already [an older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33288637/2711488) with a similar thing ;^)

Answer (score 1):

The `String.chars()` method returns an `IntStream`.  You probably want to convert it to a `Stream<Character>` via:

```
s.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char)c)
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed, you could transform the stream to primitive types to Object types.

```
s.chars().boxed()
 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```