# how to make forEach

Tags: java, foreach

I have a for:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();       
for (String o: gamma)
   map.merge(o, 1, (a, b) -> a + b);
```

I need to make forEach like this:

```
gamma.forEach(e -> map.merge(e, 1, (a, b) -> a + b));
```

But then I do like this I received a message:
Cannot invoke forEach(( e) -> {}) on the array type String[]

What I am doing wrong? How to do this forEach?

Comment: What is `gamma`?

Comment: gamma is an array of strings - String[]

Comment: Aside from main question, it looks like you want to create some kind of histogram. In that case take a look at solutions from [Producing histogram Map for IntStream raises compile-time-error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44838954). In your case you can create `Map<String, Long> histogram` with  `Stream.of(gamma).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));` or if you add static imports you can shorten this code to `Stream.of(gamma).collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting()))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this ;

```
Arrays.asList(gamma).forEach(e -> map.merge(e, 1, (a, b) -> a + b));
```

Your gamma is String array, convert to list to foreach on this.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Stream.of`: `Stream.of(gamma).forEach(e -> map.merge(e, 1, (a, b) -> a + b));`

And use [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=hp&ei=xhSmW7jmLMmqsAHNoavgBQ&q=stream%20from%20array%20java&oq=stream%20from%20array%20java&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i203k1j0i22i30k1l9.753.753.0.1166.3.2.0.0.0.0.118.118.0j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.2.187.6..35i39k1.69.fEDedtMPyWo) for your next problem!

Comment: can I do it without Stream API?

Comment: @vesnaves You use `Arrays.asList(gamma).forEach(...)` but what is wrong with Stream?

Comment: Why would you want to do it without the `Stream` API? `Arrays.stream` is also possible here, but I don't see why you would put such restrictions on yourself.

Comment: @Dici this will break for a parallel execution, generally this is documented as unneeded side effects. the much cleaner way would be `Arrays.stream(gamma).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))`

Comment: Most code that isn't meant for parallel execution will break in a multi-threaded context. I'm answering specifically about how to create a stream from an array. Otherwise yes, pure functions are recommended when using streams.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach :

```
Arrays.stream(gamma).forEach(e -> map.merge(e, 1, (a, b) -> a + b));
```